# PyQt5: Variables available and modifiable by all children widgets?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I have the current flow,

QMainWindow -> QMdiArea -> QMdiSubWindow -> QTabWidget -> QWidget -> QGraphicsScene/View

Now I want to maintain a count of a certain item being added to the scene, in a mdi sub window, Now since there can be multiple subwindows, and each subwindow can have multiple tabs. I was interested if qt had a system of given child widgets access to variables in the parent class, instead of using a self.parent().parent().... chain.

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe set your QObject names with setObjectName. Then using a reference to one of the upper object like QMainWindow, you can get references to certain objects using findChild or findChildren with some expected names.

Comment: While yes I see this as a viable option, but then I will have to keep object name reference(since there are multiple qmdisubwindows and i want the count to be seperate for each of them)  inside the the scene widget, which is then no different from what i suggested.

Comment: In addition to that, if storing the object name in the scene widget is an option, i could better yet pass the parent mdisubwindow reference and store that.